# Get bandwidth statistics of network by ip from a linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I am connected to a local network through a linux system (Ubuntu 14.04). 
Is it possible to get the bandwidth usage of other systems connected to the same network? All other systems are also using Ubuntu, however the version are different on some.

Thanks

Comment: do you need exact statistics, or just want to check who is (for example) watching movies all the time?

Comment: @lxer Sorry for replying too late, I need exact statistics.

Answer (score 1):

this would probably help you:
http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/
BandwidthD tracks usage of TCP/IP network subnets and builds html files with graphs to display utilization.

What you can see on the network without having access to the machines depends on the network structure and where the monitoring system is placed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will look into it but I am more interested in creating some kind of shell script for it myself but don't know where to start.